# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath scrolls to wrong offset with estimatedRowHeight on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am using the `estimatedRowHeight` method from UITableView in iOS 7, which works perfectly for fast loading of a UITableView with 5000 rows of variable heights.

My UITableView consists of 50 sections. Every section has 100 rows, of variable height.
At the start I use `estimatedRowHeight` for fast-loading, but after that when I call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, **my UITableView scrolls to the wrong offset**. I can understand why this is, because it has an `estimatedRowHeight` until I scroll the entire table and the proper cell heights are set in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Any solution?

Comment: Sadly, Apple hasn't fixed it after 2 years in iOS 9. Please dupe this radar to urge them: http://www.openradar.me/20829131.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this issue is to be expected when using `estimatedRowHeight` in your code with *such a low value*. When you `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` it does not **actively calculating** the correct size as you go. The underlying cause is, if you scrolled from Section 1 to Section 2, it could feasibly calculate the correct position on the fly and the `estimatedRowHeight` of the cells if it was a relatively new device. Any older devices would be brought to their knees, and even any new ones would be as well if you had to process 5000 cells, for example.

A maybe-solution to your problem could be to increase the `estimatedRowHeight` constant so the device doesn't have to do as much work.

Comment: I disagree that this is 'expected' behavior -- it's a bug that absolutely can and should be fixed by Apple. I filed a Radar soon after iOS 7 came out for this issue (it shows up in other ways as well, [click here](https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/13#issuecomment-31854501) for further discussion on the bug and some workarounds). Please file more bug reports with Apple so they prioritize fixing this.

Comment: Think about it though @simleyborg, it's just going to skip to that cell, and it certainly shouldn't have to calculate the estimated heights of EVERYTHING before it on the fly. I assume that if it still doesn't do it by iOS 7, it's not going to do it no matter how many Radars you file.

Comment: What makes you think that it has to know the actual row heights from the current scroll position to where you're scrolling to? It can apply the exact same optimization that is used when first loading the table view with a scroll position at **any** arbitrary point -- the table view shows the visible cells, and just assumes the cells above and below are of estimated height, and positions/sizes the scroll indicator as appropriate based on this. Then when cells scroll onscreen and the estimates are revised, the scroll indicator position/size is updated as well.

Comment: @smileyborg, if he's using `estimatedRowHeight` for variable height cells, to scroll to the correct pixel on the scroll view beneath the table view, the table view has to 'know' the final heights of each cell before it. Just common logic.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not correct. If that were the case, `estimatedRowHeight` would provide no benefit! To easily prove that this is not happening, load a table view using row height estimation. Then tell the table view to scroll to a cell towards the bottom of the table view. You'll see that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is **not** called for the skipped cells in between, and if you inspect the table view's `contentOffset` you'll see that it is effectively equal to `estimatedRowHeight * numberOfCellsSkipped`. Happy to upload a sample project so you can easily verify this yourself.

Comment: Let me put my two cents in. I also experienced this issue when I forgot to update the estimated row constant while my layout for a cell had been changed. I found that it is better to set higher value than a lower one, e.g. the maximum cell's height possible. In that way, scrolling to top happens as expected.

Answer (score 2):

When `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` is called, height of all the cells b/w current position and target offset are not calculated. Only some of them are.

Instead, UITableView uses `estimatedRowHeight` to calculate target offset which leads to wrong offset.

I'm facing the same issue and I found a small trick(which I don't really like) to calculate exact cell height only once after initial `relaodData`. I inserted two lines below:

```
tableView.reloadData()

// only for the initial reloadData

let numSections = tableView.numberOfSections
let numRowsInLastSection = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numSections-1)

// scrolls to the last row in the tableView
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: numRows-1, inSection: numSections-1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)

// back again to the original position(which is 0 for this is only called right after the initial reloadData)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
```

This results in the tableView appearing on the screen late, but I think it's acceptable rather than freezing UI after the tableView appeared. It's even better when you call an API on the beginning because it feels like a little delay on the network, not the UI lag.

After this, tableView jumps to exact position of the cells.

Yeah, I don't really like this solution either :|

EDIT:

The only reason I did this was to calculate actual row height by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but I found out when giving proper estimatedHeight for every row by delegate method `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of giving static value to `UITableView.estimatedRowHeight` solves the issue.

What I finally did was to cache the heights of rows from `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to disk and use that value on `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

By doing this, `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` for all rows are called in the beginning and `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` works well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest solution but I use a workaround for this issue who do the trick. Always update the estimatedRowHeight to the tallest computed cell and then use something like this :

1. Scroll the content of the tableView to offset zero.
2. Finish by calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath to index path zero.

   ```
   [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                     animated:YES];
   });
   ```

As result the tableView should scroll to the top quite smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to set the `estimatedRowHeight to 0`

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

```
let oldContentSize = tableView.contentSize
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
// Called again when tableView contentSize change
if !tableView.contentSize.equalTo(oldContentSize) {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still no solid solution but for me it was acceptable to perform a scroll without animation which worked well in the sense that it scrolls to the expected cell with the correct offset, despite of what is mentioned in http://www.openradar.me/20829131.

`self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition:.Top, animated: false)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work after the view was layouted by the system. I'm calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath with correct results in the VC's viewDidAppear. Which is not very beautiful of course, because it scrolls when the view is already visible...

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code in -cellForRowAtIndexPath: right before return the cell

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was wrong because the "atScrollPosition" was set to `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` - change it to `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` and it should work fine