# how to make a uitableview know about where to scroll for uncreated views yet

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has up to 600 items in it. They are split between headers and items (like 30 headers of 15-20 items each). It is a catalog and has to mimick the printed catalog.

There is also a navigation pop-up view that shows only the headers that a user can overlay to the main table view. It is represented like this:

```
header
 \subheader
header2
\subheader
  \subheader
```

And our code for navigating is like this:

```
  func tapOnMenuHeaderView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
  {
    self.hideModalNavigation()
    self.mainTV.reloadData()
    self.mainTV.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.menuHeaderPositions[recognizer.view!.tag]!, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
  }
```

However, it doesn't go to the right place many times. It seems to always be short and gets less accurate the further down you go. Is this a limitation to scrollRowAtIndexPath and is there a way I could force a full reload or something? The only way I could get this to work was to remove using a tableview and do everything as UIViews and just increment it in a scroll view. How would I make it so that our overlay navigation scrolls to the correct place?

### edit #1 using heightForRowAtIndexPath

So by creating and populating one of our custom cells, it did set the correct cellHeight even when using scrollToRowAtIndexPath. The important point is that automatic scrolling doesn't call cellForRowAtIndexPath. However, heightForRowAtIndexPath is called on the intial reloadData allowing for this value to calculated correctly. The code:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    println("within heightForRowAtIndexPath \(indexPath.row)")
    let item = self.tableItems[indexPath.row];
    if let menuHeader = item as? EKMenuHeader {
      // cellHeight is a property on the models that is defaulted to 0.0
      if (menuHeader.cellHeight == 0.0){
        let tableViewCell = EKMenuHeaderCell()
        tableViewCell.updateCell(menuHeader)
      }
      return CGFloat(menuHeader.cellHeight)
    } else if let menuItem = item as? EKMenuItem {
      if (menuItem.cellHeight == 0.0){
        let tableViewCell = EKMenuItemCell()
        tableViewCell.updateCell(menuItem)
      }
      return CGFloat(menuItem.cellHeight) // not the default value
    }else{
      return 30.0  // some that are neither
    }
  }
```

I have tested this like 10 different times and heightForRowAtIndexPath is called for all 350 items.

Comment: Scrolling is based on estimated row height.  The more accurate the estimate, the closer the table can scroll to the correct offset for a cell or section header.

Comment: It's supposed to scroll to the exact index position. If I scroll to like position 500, then scroll to top, it is able to figure it out so the implication would seem to be that it just doesn't know about this location's position. It seems like you should be able to force it to calculate that intended position.

Comment: It doesn't know the exact position, because it hasn't calculated the exact height of every cell between its current indexPath and new indexPath.  I assure you it scrolls to an estimated offset for the indexPath.  It can't determine the exact position, unless it had scrolled row-by-row and determined every exact height preceding the new indexPath.  Use a more exact estimate, or the error will be more noticeable, as your question mentions, the further it has to estimate.

Comment: hmm... I have the feeling there's a workaround to make this work. What you're saying is that the method doesn't do it's description `Scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.` ; wouldn't be the first time but a bit disconcerting

Comment: Read smileyborg's comments in the answer to [UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath scrolls to wrong offset with estimatedRowHeight on iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20973135/4151918).  The method isn't doing what you think it's doing.  It won't populate data for every row.  If you use `estimatedRowHeight`,  `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, or `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, there will be inaccuracy, which will increase the further you scroll, unless your estimate happens to match the actual height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` uses `estimatedRowHeight` (or `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`) to determine an *approximate* offset for the row you're scrolling to.  The tableView will then display that row, along with any other surrounding rows that may be visible.

It doesn't literally scroll, row by row, calculating exact row heights of cells as it scrolls, as that would not be efficient.

That's why, the further you scroll, the further off the position will be when the estimate is not very accurate.

Unless you have the tableView calculate exact heights for every row in the table, it won't be able to scroll to the precise position where the row actually would be located.

Since you're trying to "sync" the position of the table rows with overlaid headers in a separate view, you'll either have to:

- abandon using any estimation at all, and resort to calculating exact heights for every row in the table (by removing any automatic or estimated sizing, and implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`).
- wait until the table has scrolled, determine the visible offset, and **then adjust the overlay to line it up** with the table's approximated location for the row.

*You could also move the overlaid data into the tableView headers, so there's no longer any need to keep two independent views in sync.*

Comment: thx Petah - a couple of complex decisions. I do calculate the exact height of the table view cells are you are scrolling currently but obviously this only occurs if the table view has been scrolled to this point.  I get the idea of it not being efficient but when implemented as 1000 UITableViews (rather than a UITableView with 1000 records), the performance is fine.

Comment: Thinking through this, since the navigation piece would be called after the initial table has been populated, would it be possible to do something like scroll to the bottom of the table so that all the information for scrollToRowAtIndexPath gets populated? Ideally, off screen so that there's nothing in the UI to see this? I was thinking of doing the headers as sections but I am not sure if that will help at all.

Comment: If you're at the top, and you `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` to the very last row, it *doesn't* calculate the height of every single cell as it scrolls.  You can verify this by logging and seeing that only the height of the last row and nearby cells are calculated.  It uses the estimatedRowHeight to estimate the height of the cells that aren't visible.  That's the purpose of the estimate, to avoid having to determine the height of every row, but it does introduce this 'error' where an inaccurate estimate will introduce a discrepancy between the table's perceived (estimated) size and its true size.

Comment: Programmatically scrolling to the bottom will not populate exact height information for all the rows.  Manually scrolling to the bottom will.  You can't programmatically scroll to the bottom and expect it to determine every cell height, but you **can** stop using estimates which will force the table to calculate heights for every row, even before programmatically scrolling the table.  (estimatedRowHeight was added in iOS 7.  Before that optimization, the tableView actually had to calculate all cell heights to know its content size.)

Comment: thx for comment, I updated the question with what looks like a sol'n in edit #1. I think this is what you're getting at in your first sol'n

Comment: Yes, that's the first solution I suggested, and what I was referring to in the previous comment.  Because your tableView can now determine the height for every row, it now can scroll to the precise offset for that row, regardless of how much further down you programmatically scrolled.  And yes, as you discovered, it will be called for every row, whenever the table is (re)loaded.  You can also optimize that by only reloading specific rows or sections, instead of reloading the entire table.